# Sorting the table not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

Following the #240 Railscasts i have a list of names like this

`arnold
Arnold
Victor`

And when I order this by that method, i get this in asc

`Arnold
Victor
arnold`

And this in desc

`arnold
Victor
Arnold`

In my controller I have:

```
def index  
  @alunos = Aluno.search(params[:search]).order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction).paginate(:per_page => params[:npage], :page => params[:page])
end  

def sort_column
  Aluno.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "nome"
end
```

And this in my application_helper

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def sortable(column, title = nil)
    title ||= column.titleize
    css_class = column == sort_column ? "current #{sort_direction}" : nil
    direction = column == sort_column && sort_direction == "asc" ? "desc" : "asc"
    link_to title, params.merge(:sort => column.downcase, :direction => direction, :page => nil), {:class => css_class}
  end
end
```

And I'm getting this (desc, in this example):

[image]

There is something that i must include in my controller or models to order in case INsensitive?

--edited
Im using sqlite3

Comment: What is the underlying datastore? MySQL? Postgres?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using SQL as the underlying datastore, you could do

```
@alunos = Aluno.search(params[:search]).order("LOWER(#{sort_column}) #{sort_direction}").paginate(:per_page => params[:npage], :page => params[:page])
```